# How to handle virtual resources with the python rest-framework eve

Tags: eve

I'm new to the python rest-framework called 'eve'. I read the documentation and it sounds very cool. But before I start to evaluate it as framework for coming projects, I have the following question:

It seems to me that a request always fetchs *one* resource from the database and with event hooks it's possible to modify the resource before returning to the client.

But sometimes it's useful to use 'virtual' instead of 'real' resources. With 'virtual' I mean a resource that isn't stored in the database, instead it will be created on the fly for every request. Often multiple real resources are necessary to create such a virtual resource, so it's necessary to fetch and process *multiple* real objects from the database.

How does this demand fit in the eve approach?

Thank you, rgds
Fin

Answer (score 1):

Eve is a Flask application (a Flask subclass in fact) so nothing prevents you from binding your own routes and custom functions, or even add a Flask Blueprint. For a working example, check out the [Eve-Docs](https://github.com/charlesflynn/eve-docs) extension, which add an HTML-only `/docs` endpoint to the API (intended for human consumption).

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks for your answer. So for this scenario there is no "eve approach", rather I have to use Flash mechanisms - Ok :)